# Push_back elements dissapear after being added

Tags: c++, oop

I have this message class which has a vector of Message pointers called child_list. child_list is supposed to contain the address of each reply made to that topic or reply to a reply etc. I import a series of messages into an all inclusive message pointer vector for each message address from a .txt file. I then go back through the file and check for the 'children' reply's made to each message. My problem happens right after I push_back the address of the replys to that message.
I can see the child_list.size() grow as I add elements, but right after the for loop is done I try to print out the message and I see the child_string.size() is now 0. Why are the message pointers being destroyed before I can use them?

```
    //bboard.cpp
    void Bboard::display() const
    {
        cout << endl;
        message_list[0]->print();
        cout << endl;
    }

    //add each child to the message
    for(unsigned m = 0; m < children.size(); ++m)
    {
        cout << "id to add: " << children[m] << endl;
        Message * tempPTR = message_list[ children[m]-1 ];
        cout << "tempPTR: " << tempPTR << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "\tdisplay BEFORE push to message_list[id]->add_child(tempPTR): " << endl;
        display();
        message_list[id]->add_child(tempPTR);
        cout << endl;
        display();
        cout << "\tdisplay AFTER push to message_list[id]->add_child(tempPTR): " << endl;
    }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "After the for loop to add them: " << endl;
        display();

//message.cpp
void Message::add_child(Message* child)
{
    this->child_list.push_back(child);
    cout << "\tchild_list size: " << child_list.size() << endl;
}

//topic.cpp
//Message::print() is true virtual and is defined here for Topic
void Topic::print() const
{
    cout << "Message #" << this->id << ": " << this->subject << endl;
    cout << "from " << this->author << ": " << this->body << endl;
    cout << "child_list Size: " << this->child_list.size() << endl;
    //later, I need to add a for loop to display all the child messages
}
```

Ouput to terminal showing addresses of messages and the child_list pointers before deletion.

### From Terminal:

message id: 1 is at address: 0x8d45870

message id: 2 is at address: 0x8d45a30

message id: 3 is at address: 0x8d45b60

message id: 4 is at address: 0x8d45da0

message id: 5 is at address: 0x8d45ae0

message id: 6 is at address: 0x8d45fe0

message id: 7 is at address: 0x8d46170

message id: 8 is at address: 0x8d46260

message id: 9 is at address: 0x8d46310

message id: 10 is at address: 0x8d45f90

id: 1

children: 6 9

children[m]: 6

tempPTR: 0x8d45fe0

display BEFORE push to message_list[id]->add_child(tempPTR):

Message #1:  CS12 Assignment 7

from  messi:  The assignment is hard so go step by step.

You can read the Tips & Tricks part for some help.

child_list Size: 0

child->id: 6

child added to list: 0x8d45fe0

child_list size: 1

Message #1:  CS12 Assignment 7

from  messi:  The assignment is hard so go step by step.

You can read the Tips & Tricks part for some help.

child_list Size: 0

display AFTER push to message_list[id]->add_child(tempPTR):

children[m]: 9

tempPTR: 0x8d46310

display BEFORE push to message_list[id]->add_child(tempPTR):

Message #1:  CS12 Assignment 7

from  messi:  The assignment is hard so go step by step.

You can read the Tips & Tricks part for some help.

child_list Size: 0

child->id: 9

child added to list: 0x8d46310

child_list size: 2

Message #1:  CS12 Assignment 7

from  messi:  The assignment is hard so go step by step.

You can read the Tips & Tricks part for some help.

child_list Size: 0

display AFTER push to message_list[id]->add_child(tempPTR):

After the for loop to add them:

Message #1:  CS12 Assignment 7

from  messi:  The assignment is hard so go step by step.

You can read the Tips & Tricks part for some help.

child_list Size: 0

Comment: I think it would help if you show the code where you see child_string.size() == 0.

Comment: Also, what is children a list of?  ints?  Your loop is using an index type called unsigned; I think you mean unsigned int. What is id?  Is it an int?  More code and context would be helpful.

Comment: @dusk: `unsigned` is synonym to `unsigned int`.

Comment: I thought 'unsigned' and 'unsigned int' were the same thing, am I mistaken? The IDs are all of type 'unsigned' as well.

Comment: @MikeTrottman : You're not mistaken.

Comment: @MikeTrottman - Why are you doing **-1** in the statement - `Message * tempPTR = message_list[ children[m]-1 ];` ? Also there is no need to use **this** on a member variable when being in the scope of the class unless there is clash with the name of the call parameter and the member variable. ( `this->child_list.push_back(child);` )

Comment: @Mahesh I have to say -1 because the value held in the children vector are the IDs of each message in 'message_list', and the IDs are 1 higher than their index in 'message_list'. IE: 'message[0]' has an ID of 1.

Comment: Like a ton of bricks @Mahesh. After your comment I realized that the line where I wrote 'message_list[id]->add_child(tempPTR);' I should have wrote 'message_list[id-1]->add_child(tempPTR);'. I was associating the pointers to the wrong ID the whole time. Thank you all very much for your help! And thank goodness for the boards on Stackoverflow.com where I can go to publicly express my foolish oversight!

Answer (score 0):

You are adding to the list with the method `void Message::add_child(Message* child)`, and then trying to print out a list with `void Topic::print() const`.

Do `Message` and `Topic` classes relate to each other through inheritance? or are they both holding a reference to the same `child_list` instance?

From the code you posted i think there are multiple `child_list` vectors and you are printing from the wrong one perhaps?

Comment: add_child is inherited from Message to both topid and reply objects. Perhaps it is trying to print the wrong child_list though.

Comment: perhaps show the code that happens between your add child loop and the print calls

Comment: 'Topic' and 'Reply' classes both inherit 'Message' and 'add_child()' is only declared in 'Message'. When I call 'message_list[x]->print();' it checks the 'this->child_list.size()' for that object could it still be asking for a different 'child_list' than the one I was earlier 'push_back'ing to? I can post more code if need be, what else should I add?

Comment: @MikeTrottman - well i guess an easy test would be to add a message_list[id]->print(); call both before and after your message_list[id]->add_child(tempPTR); calls to ensure that both methods are referring to the same object.

Comment: @Vusak 'display()' is the calls a print command which I have right now only printing the first element in the 'message_list'. When 'message_list->print()' is called I have it printing the 'child_list.size()' so I can see if there are elements in that vector or not. This is how I have it setup so far while I try to troubleshoot this.

Comment: @Vusak I'll try to print before and after the fact and post what I tried above. Good idea.

Comment: Okay I added a bunch of stuff and it looks like before and after the 'push_back' 'child_list.size()' remains at zero. Am I not accessing the 'message_list' elements 'child_list' correctly?

Comment: @MikeTrottman - Where you have the code "display();", replace it with "message_list[id]->print();", that will tell you if the problem is in display or in your Message Topic child_list relationship.